# Optimal data structure for calculation

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, collections, hashmap

I have a problem in which I would like to use the optimal solution with least line of code.

**Problem**

I have 4 bowls, each bowl has few number of coins and the sum of these coins is an amount.[image]

Now, I want to calculate the difference in number of coins by each bowl.

1. Bowl # 1 has 1 coin of 5 and 3 coins of 1.
2. Bowl # 2 has 1 coin of 20 and 1 coin of 5

In this case Bowl # 1-> Bowl # 2 difference:

1. coin of 5 = 1 + 1 => 2 => (2-1)*100 / 2 => 50%
2. coin of 1 = 3 + 0 => 3 => (3 - 0) * 100 / 3 => 100%
3. coin of 20 =  0 + 1 => 1 => (1 - 0) * 100 / 1 => 100%

I have created one

```
Map<String, List<DTO>> result;
```

where DTO consist on two properties; Integer and String. Integer hold the number of coins and String holds the name of coin. Put it in Map against Bowl.

In the end I get one map with 4 keys:

1. Bowl # 1 holds a list with 4 objects.
2. Bowl # 2 holds a list with 2 objects.
3. Bowl # 3 holds a list with 2 objects.
4. Bowl # 4 holds a list with 3 objects.

Now, my problem is in getting the change percentage in each bowl in comparison of it's previous bowl.

EDIT: The calculation uses percentage change formula similar to `(a - b)/b = c` except is `(a - b)/a = c`

Comment: It's not clear what do you want to get in the end. Matrix (number of bowls)x(number of coins) with calculated percentages?

Comment: I want change percentage of coins in each bowl

Comment: Define "change percentage" formally, please. From your explanation I understood that for pair of bowls you compute the percentage of coins that is located in this located in one of the bowls. Do you want to calculate a percentage of coins among all coins of particular type for each bowl (basically matrix that I mentioned above)?

Comment: BTW, point 3 should be corrected to "Coins 20: (0 + 1) => (1 - 1) * 100 / 1 => 0 %"? Am I right?

Comment: I.e how many coins of 5 added in bowl #2 and removed from bowl #2 in comparison with bowl # 1. Similarly if I go for bowl # 3 then how many coins of 5 added and how many coins of 20 and 1 removed.

Comment: So, for each (i,j,k) i != j you want to know |count_of_k_in_i - count_of_k_in_j| / (count_of_k_in_i + count_of_k_in_j) * 100? Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes somewhat only one thing it can be bidirectional as if number is greater in bowl # 1 then subtraction will be from bowl # 1- bowl #2 else bowl#2-bowl#1

Comment: If bowl # 1 has 1 coin of 20 and bowl # 2 has 0 coin of 20 then change is 100%. If bowl # 2 has 1 coin of 20 and bowl #1 has 0 coin of 20 then change is  again 100%.